# What is proper way to have a "finally" / "complete" code block for a subscription?

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have a modal, with a button that is disabled when clicked, and then makes an api call..  Regardless of success or failure, I want to enable the button upon api call completion.  If it's successful, then dismiss the modal.  If it fails, show an error message.

```
this.buttonDisabled = true;
this.client.post(this.formGroup.value).pipe(
  first()
).subscribe(
  () => this.dismissModal(),
  (error) => this.setError(error),
  () => { this.buttonDisabled = false; }
)
```

I am seeing the success and failure functions get called, but not the "finalize/complete" one...  Is there another way to have shared code between success/failure without duplicating it?

Also, just want to verify I am doing the pipe/first/subscribe thing right..  This approach, I do not need to unsubscribe right?  because I did `first()` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the finalize pipe operator

```
this.client.post(this.formGroup.value).pipe(
  first(),
   finalize(() => this.buttonDisabled = false;),
).subscribe(
  () => this.dismissModal(),
  (error) => this.setError(error),
 )
```